# Decrease product in store when I sell product?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to decrease 25 quantity from 2 row with different expire date on different coming date I want decrease 20 from first amount and 5 from second amount remaining amount will be 45 at second and the first one will be come 0 I need use a query to do this

This query retrieve my data

| Name | Barcode | Quantity | Expire | InDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coke | 11 | 20 | 2025-03-10 | 2024-01-01 |
| Coke | 11 | 50 | 2026-01-05 | 2024-02-06 |

after executing query I need my table become like this

| Name | Barcode | Quantity | Expire | InDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coke | 11 | 0 | 2025-03-10 | 2024-01-01 |
| Coke | 11 | 45 | 2026-01-05 | 2024-02-06 |

and I use this query but not working

```
update ProductIn
set Quantity=Quantity-25
where Barcode=11
```

Comment: Thats a very complicated topic, and certainly requires a far more complex query than you've tried. I suggest searching for "sql stock allocation"

Comment: How do you make sure the first to expire bottles are sold first? Some customers look for the opposite, or just pick randomly.

Comment: This is now the 3rd time you've posted this question though; if you had used the edit feature on your first question, an address the problems then, you likely wouldn't be on the verge (or over the verge) fo a question ban.

Answer (score 0):

As Dale mention, it is a complicated topic. If what you need is just simple FIFO (First In First Out), the following query works for your requirement

The query uses `sum()` with window function to calculate the cumulative available quantity. It then case expression to compare the `@Quantity` to deduct with the cumulative quantity and calculate the `allocQty` allocated quantity (quantity to deduct)

```
declare @Barcode  int = 11,
        @Quantity int = 25;

with alloc as
(
  select Barcode, Quantity, InDate, 
         allocQty = case when sum(Quantity) over (partition by Barcode order by InDate)
                         <=   @Quantity
                         then Quantity
                         when sum(Quantity) over (partition by Barcode order by InDate)
                         -    Quantity 
                         <=   @Quantity
                         then @Quantity 
                         -    sum(Quantity) over (partition by Barcode order by InDate)
                         +    Quantity
                         else 0
                       e  nd
  from   ProductIn
  where  Barcode = @Barcode
  and    Quantity > 0
)
update alloc 
set    Quantity = Quantity - allocQty
where  allocQty > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what yoiu need to do is use a running total, and then `UPDATE` all the rows where the running total minus the current row is less than or equal to the value to decrease by.

Let's create some sample data first.

```sql
SELECT V.Name,
       CONVERT(int,V.Barcode) AS Barcode,
       CONVERT(int,V.Quantity) AS Quantity,
       CONVERT(date,V.Expire) AS Expire,
       CONVERT(date,V.InDate) AS InDate
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('Coke','11','20','2025-03-10','2024-01-01'),
            ('Coke','11','50','2026-01-05','2024-02-06'),
            ('Coke','11','35','2027-02-19','2024-03-15'))V(Name,Barcode,Quantity,Expire,InDate);
GO
```

To be able to use a running total, we'll want to use windowed aggregate functions. As, however, we want to use these as part as an `UPDATE` as well we need to use an `UPDATE`able CTE (or derived table), so that we can define those totals and then use them in both the `SET` and `WHERE` clauses.

To know what rows to update, we can check if the prior total is less than the value to decrease by. Then, we can use the running total to see if we need to `0` the value ,because the decrease is larger than the stock, or  just reduce the value by the remainder.

This gives us the following solution:

```sql
DECLARE @Barcode int = 11,
        @Decrease int = 25;

WITH Quantities AS (
    SELECT YT.Quantity,
           SUM(YT.Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY YT.Expire ASC
                                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningQuantity,
           ISNULL(SUM(YT.Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY YT.Expire ASC
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS PriorQuantity
       
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.Barcode = @Barcode
      AND YT.Quantity > 0) --Because we don't need to consider depleted inventory
UPDATE Q
SET Quantity = CASE WHEN Q.RunningQuantity < @Decrease THEN 0 ELSE Q.Quantity - (@Decrease - Q.PriorQuantity) END
FROM Quantities Q
WHERE Q.PriorQuantity <= @Decrease;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
GO
```

Clean up:

```sql
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```